# Is my proof of "$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous implies $g(x) = (x,f(x))$ continuous" valid?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

The problem goes as follows:

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}_\text{usual} \to \mathbb{R}_\text{usual}$ be continuous and let $g: \mathbb{R}_\text{usual} \to \mathbb{R}_\text{usual}^2$ be defined as $g(x) = (x, f(x))$. Show that $g$ is continuous.

> Note : $\mathbb R_{\text{usual}}$ denotes the set $\mathbb R$ equipped with the usual topology induced by the euclidian metric.

It is supposed to be a moderately challenging problem in the [biglist](http://www.math.toronto.edu/ivan/mat327/docs/biglist.pdf) (Chapter 6 problem 10). But I solved it quite easily and now I am doubting my solution.

Here's my solution.

To show that $g$ is continuous, we need to use the fact that the product of two continuous functions is continuous. Consider the projection functions $\pi_1(g(x)) = x$ and $\pi_2(g(x)) = f(x)$. Since the projection function is continuous and we can write $g(x) = (\pi_1(x, f(x)), \pi_2(x, f(x)))$, hence the resulting function $g$ is also continuous.

Is there a basis for my skepticism or is my solution really buggy? Any help is welcome...

Comment: Pardon my ignorance: What is $\mathbb{R}_\text{usual}$?

Comment: @MartinR $\mathbb{R}_\text{usual}$ is the usual topology generated on the set of reals. Like for example when you consider the Euclidean Distance metric. It is a short-hand for the same

Comment: Your ignorance is pardoned :)

Comment: As long as you know/have already proved why $g$ being continuous is equivalent to $\pi_1\circ g$ and $\pi_2\circ g$ being continuous, you’re fine.

Comment: @peek-a-boo please feel free to add any other proof

Comment: no, any other proof will essentially repeat that argument (even if in a hidden manner), for example if I tried a direct $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof using the Euclidean metric on both spaces.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Can you add your proof here?\

Comment: If it is the usual topology then why specify ? The shorthand for $\mathbb R$ with the usual topology is just $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Your proof is absolutely fine. I think the author of the question set was having a blank moment when classifying the problem as challenging.